# Can I create a template within XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to create a ASP.NET user control from an XML using XSLT.
Currently I really put the result together bit by bit:

```
<xsl:template match="TextField">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="Label" />
   <xsl:text><![CDATA[<asp:TextBox ID="]]></xsl:text>
   <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>
   <xsl:if test="@defaultValue">
      <xsl:text><![CDATA[" value="]]></xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="@defaultValue"/>
   </xsl:if>
   <xsl:text><![CDATA[" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>]]></xsl:text>
   <xsl:copy-of select="$br"/>
</xsl:template>
```

It would be rally cool if I could instead do something like this:

```
<xsl:template match="TextField">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="Label" />

   <xsl:variable name="localTemplate" select="expression">
      <xsl:text><![CDATA[
         <asp:TextBox ID="{theID}" value="{theDefaultValue}" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
      ]]></xsl:text>
      <xsl:copy-of select="$br"/>
   </xsl:variable>

   <!-- replace {theID} and {theDefaultValue} from the corresponding
       values of the input XML and then return the content of that
       variable
   -->
</xsl:template>
```

Because that seems much cleaner and more easy to maintain later on when there is the need to change the html structure.

Is there a way to achieve this and if yes, how would that look like?
I don't need a working solution, just some hints on what to do.

Update: Here is some sample input XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="XmlForm.xsd">

   <Validation enabled="false" enableValidationSummary="true" />
   <FieldSet>
      <TextField id="firstInput" css-class="textfield-css-class" />

      <TextField id="secondInput" defaultValue="Wrdlbmrpft">
         <Label translatable="true" >Label Text</Label>
      </TextField>
   </FieldSet>
</Form>
```

The output should look like this:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" Inherits="DevelopmentWeb.WebUserControl1" %>
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="firstInput" CssClass="textfield-css-class"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="secondInput">Label Text</asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="secondInput">Wrdlbrmpft</asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there would be any reason to create a variable. You should be able to do something like this:

```
  <xsl:template match="TextField">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Label" />
    <asp:TextBox ID="{@id}" value="{@defaultValue}" runat="server"/>    
    <xsl:copy-of select="$br"/>
  </xsl:template>
```

or this:

```
  <xsl:template match="TextField">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Label" />
    <asp:TextBox runat="server">
      <xsl:if test="@id">
        <xsl:attribute name="ID">
          <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:if>    
      <xsl:if test="@defaultValue">
        <xsl:attribute name="value">
          <xsl:value-of select="@defaultValue"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:if>
    </asp:TextBox>
    <xsl:copy-of select="$br"/>
  </xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Define appropriate namespace for prefix asp, e.g.:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:asp="System.Web.UI.WebControls">
```

In your template simply write:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="{@id}" runat="server">
    <xsl:if test="@defaultValue">
        <xsl:attribute name="value">
            <xsl:value-of select="@defaultValue"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:if>
</asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: @Sebastian, So provide your input XML and desired output.

Comment: The output is of course (must be) text, because we have to create specific html given by some design agencies that is not valid. This isn't good, but we have to stick to it. I'll update the question with some input XML.

Comment: @Sebastian, I mean structure of output XML.

Comment: Also added to the question. Right now there are no html elements in there yet, but there will be a point where there are tables or div-structures to be added around the controls which will result in invalid xml, so I definetly need to use cdata for these because that will break the xsl

Comment: @Sebastian, Your XML won't be well-formed, so you need to output XML like text.